# ASP.NET Web API - GET HTTP Verb not supported (405) when attempting to pass a parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am attempting to call my Web API with a getJSON request:

```
var uri = 'api/comment';
var id = solicitorId;

$.getJSON(uri, id, (function (data) {
    $('#commentTableContainer').html(data);
}));
```

And this is the method in the comment Controller class:

```
public string GetComment(int id)
{
    //Do things
}
```

I am using the default routing:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

However, when trying to call the api with getJSON I receive a 405 error:

```
HTTP405: BAD METHOD - The HTTP verb used is not supported.
(XHR)GET - http://localhost:<port>/api/comment?334203
```

The GET request works if I remove the `id` parameter from GetComment signature, i.e. `GetComment()`

I don't know too much about this WebAPI stuff - I mostly followed a guide from Microsoft, here [here (learn.microsoft.com)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api)

If anyone has any ideas I would be grateful. I've looked at many SO questions on this, but none have helped.

I've tried adding `[HTTPGet]` to the CommentController `GetComment(int id)` method, as well as specifying the route with `[Route]` but I am getting nowhere at all.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Route mapping you show should not map `api/comment`, unless you have controller named `api`.

Comment: I'd expect the URI should be `http://localhost:<port>/api/comment?id=334203` (note the `id=`). Or simply just `http://localhost:<port>/api/comment/334203` with a `/` instead of a `?`, depending upon what routing is actually being used here.

Answer (score 4):

Your Route config might not match your URL.

Route config : `url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}"`

Request URL : `/api/comment?334203`

you can try to add `Route` attribute to set [RouteAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) for your API action.

```
[Route("api/comment/{id}")]
[HttpGet]
public string GetComment(int id)
{
    //Do things
}
```

and you need to use full url on your ajax request.

```
var uri = 'http://localhost:<port>/api/comment/GetComment';
```

that can match your route setting.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It certainly changed things, I now get a 404: `HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).` which is something different to look into at least

Comment: @MarcosFoster Sorry I edit my answer I forget the parameter

Comment: Unfortunately no, still getting the same 404.

Comment: What about Request URL, `/api/comment?id=334203`

Comment: @MarcosFoster you can try to set full URL(include port number) in your request URL

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. You all pointed me in the right direction and it seems that the routing was expecting the format `{controller}/{action}/{id}` and not `{controller}/{action}?{id}` if that makes sense. See my answer for what I ended up changing

Answer (score 1):

Just try the url in the browser =http://localhost:/api/comment/GetComment?334203. Maybe you are missing the method name in from the URL.

Also, the webApi.Config is used for the Web API. Let me know if it not works.

Comment: If I do that I get:

`The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.String GetComment(Int32)'` 

which is interesting. Making the parameter nullable (`GetComment(int? id)`) means the method is actually hit, but no ID is supplied

Comment: In which case, you should now just change your `?` to a `/`. If that doesn't do it, change it to `?id=334203` (I can't be sure how your routing is actually working).

Answer (score 0):

and thank you so much for the help. 
I have fixed it now. I don't really know exactly how to describe this, but I changed my `$.getJSON` call to this:

```
var uri = 'api/comment/' + id;
$.getJSON(uri, (function (data) {
    //immaterial things
}
```

And my CommentController method back to just `public string GetComment(int id)` without the `[Route]` or `[HTTPGet]`

And it now works. I completely thought I had tried this before, but no. I would not have been able to fix this without everyone's suggestions so thank you so much and have a good weekend!

Answer (score 0):

first of all change WebApiConfig file and edit default route like below .

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

When you change route template and add "{action}" parameter , this mean you must add action name when you want to call action

and after that you can call function like below url

```
var uri = 'http://localhost:<port>/api/comment/GetComment/'+id;
```

I hope this help you